# vue application hook for initial load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

We have an application loader that is meant to be displayed when initially loading the application.

My solution was to hook into the 'mounted' hook of the layout, since all pages share the same layout.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this, as it seems like this is retriggered when switching back to the tab after it has been inactive for awhile.

Comment: The question doesn't reflect your case, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown how this layout com is related to the app. If it's mounted once then it's mounted once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your load screen inside the main app element. The content is replaced by Vue during the first render.

```
<div id='app'>
  <h5>App is loading!</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: i should've specified this but i'm using vuetify so my markup isn't exactly the same. are you of aware of the vuetify version of this?

Comment: As long as you do not want your splash screen to contain reactive elements, this should work for Vuetify too. Go to _/public/index.html_ and add your splash screen markup to the #app element.